# Dolbeault cohomology and analytic regularity

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-geometry, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be a complex analytic $n$-manifold. The Dolbeault cohomology complex is defined using a quotient space of smooth differential forms. My question is : would it make a big difference if we were to use $C^n$ sections instead, or $C^2$, or even differential forms in Sobolev spaces ?

(obviously with at least enough regularity to define $\overline{\partial}$)

EDIT

A bit more precision : if I were to consider the quotient space
$A/B$, where $A$ is the space of $C^1$ $(p,q)$-forms $\alpha$ for which $\overline{\partial} \alpha=0$ and $B$ is the set of $\overline{\partial}$ of $C^2 (p,q-1)$-forms, would I get the same dimension as $H^{p,q}$ ? What if I were to replace $C^2$ and $C^1$ by Sobolev spaces with distributional derivatives of order $2$ and $1$ in $L^p$ ?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, even with the edit. When you have a complex $M^{\bullet}$, all the spaces are fixed ($C^1$, say) beforehand. You can't just decide that some of them will be $C^2$ when it suits you because you need to quotient. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You can very well consider the quotient A/B as I defined it, and wonder about its dimension, even if it is not a cohomology space, can you not ?

Comment: Indeed, nobody can stop you from doing that. But in that case you should change the question's title and body since it has nothing to do with complexes in general and Dolbeault cohomology in particular.

Comment: I don't think it is reasonable to say that it has nothing with the Dolbeault cohomology. Even more so because my question is precisely if A/B has the same dimension as the Dolbeault cohomology !

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a complex of chains. If you are considering class $C^1$ forms then $\bar{\partial}$ does not have values in class $C^1$ forms, hence you can hardly define $\bar{\partial} \circ \bar{\partial}$, which is crucial because in cohomology you ask that $Im(\bar{\partial}) \subset Ker(\bar{\partial})$.

Comment: That is why I edited to $C^2$. Also it does not answer for $C^n$ maps, or maps with say, distributional derivatives of order up to $n$ in $L^2$

Comment: Well, for $C^2$, you can define $\partial(\partial f)$, but you still can't define a complex of chains : $\partial$ still doesn't map $C^n$ into $C^n$ (unless you want to take class $C^{d+1}$ for $0$-forms, class $C^{d}$ for $1$-forms, class $C^{d-1}$ for $2$-forms...)

Comment: OK, let's be rigorous. Please see the edit of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be a locally free sheaf on an $n$-dimensional complex manifold $X$.

The obvious is to consider the complex

$$
O_X(F) \to A_X^{0,0,r}(F) \to A_X^{0,1,r-1}(F)\to \dots \to A_X^{0,n,r-n}(F) \to 0
$$

where $A_X^{p,q,s}(F)$ denotes the space of $(p,q)$ forms on $X$ with values in $F$ of class $C^s$, and all differentials are $\overline \partial$.

This does not work if $r$ is an integer, but does work if $r=k+\alpha$ for $k>n$ an integer and $0<\alpha<1$, i.e., if the appropriate derivatives are Holder of exponent $\alpha$.  This complex does then compute the cohomology of the locally free sheaf $F$. This is because in this Holder class the Dolbeault resolution is exact and fine.

But there is a loss of domain when convolving with the Cauchy kernel, and it is harder to make this work on open domains, however pseudo convex.